# DOUNTIL IN CL AS400

Tags: ibm-midrange

```
PGM
DCL        VAR(&I) TYPE(*INT) VALUE(1)    
DCL        VAR(&OUT) TYPE(*CHAR) LEN(3)   
DOUNTIL    COND(&I < 10)                  
CHGVAR     VAR(&OUT) VALUE(&I)            
SNDUSRMSG  MSG(&OUT)                      
CHGVAR     VAR(&I) VALUE(&I +1)           
ENDDO                                     
ENDPGM
```

In above program `DOUNTIL` is executing once. Can anyone explain me the reason for it?

Comment: Debug is your friend

Comment: `Can anyone explain me the reason for it?` That's easy. The **reason** is that the condition ( &I < 10 ) is satisfied after the first time through. Since you didn't say what you want the program to do, we can't provide much help.

Answer (score 0):

To fix it:

```
DOUNTIL COND(&I > 10)
```

or

```
DOWHILE COND(&I <= 10)
```